# Cross language simple expression language implementation

Tags: java, javascript, scala

Does there exist a very simple expression language that has parsers in one of the following languages:

- JavaScript
- Scala
- Java

The operations I want to perform on objects are similar to angular expressions. http://teropa.info/blog/2014/03/23/angularjs-expressions-cheatsheet.html

However I do not require all of them, since I want language independent functionality. The object exposed to the expression should be JSON. Meaning I don't need to allow for function calls for instance. Filter functionality isn't needed either.

What I want to use this for is for simple validation expressions shared between language implementations.

Given the following person

```
{
    age: 17,
    male: false,
    country: 'US'
}
```

I would maybe want to define validation rules like this

```
{
    age: "(male && age >= 16) || (!male && age >= 18)", // => conditionally valid
    country: "country == 'US'" // => valid
}
```

What alternatives do I have for simple expressions like this that should return true or false? The operators does not need to be as in the examples above. `and` is fine instead of `&&` or `lt` is fine instead of `<` etc.

I have seen some alternatives like http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el007.htm#BNAIM but the problems with those that I have seen is that they are meant for use in a specific context and have several implicit variables. And they have things like lambda expressions etc. which makes writing possible missing implementation in a language much more complex.

Comment: What's wrong with EL having specific variables? Simply don't use them. In any case you could investigate using the Javascript engine built into the JDK. That's far from a simple language, but you can still use it to evaluate simple conditions.

Comment: Well that means restrictions on names on my objects. It's not a super serious issue, but I'd prefer it not having that. Also it introduces more complexity.

Comment: Do you mean "_one_ of the following languages" or "_each_ of the following languages"?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Expression Language has support for Java, Javascript and .NET:

- https://github.com/benmarch/spel2js
- http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html

I've used the .NET and Java versions and they are mostly fine, though there are some inconsistencies between the two.

You could also use JavaScript itself, many modern languages can parse and evaluate JavaScript.